# Get element starting with letter from List

Tags: java, android, list, indexof

I have a list and I want to get the position of the string which starts with specific letter.
I am trying this code, but it isn't working.

```
List<String> sp = Arrays.asList(splited);
int i2 = sp.indexOf("^w.*$");
```

Comment: Is this the full string "^w.*$?

Comment: Looks like you want to use a regular expression. `indexOf` will check if any String in your list is equals to `"^w.*$"`, not that matches `"^w.*$"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `indexOf` method doesn't accept a regex pattern. Instead you could do a method like this:

```
public static int indexOfPattern(List<String> list, String regex) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        String s = list.get(i);
        if (s != null && pattern.matcher(s).matches()) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

And then you simply could write:

```
int i2 = indexOfPattern(sp, "^w.*$");
```

Answer (score 1):

[`indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-) doesn't accept a regex, you should iterate on the list and use [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) and [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to achieve that:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^w.*$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.print(matcher.start());
}
```

---

Maybe I misunderstood your question. If you want to find the index in the list of the first string that begins with "w", then my answer is irrelevant. You should iterate on the list, check if the string [`startsWith`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith-java.lang.String-) that string, and then return its index.

Comment: Yes I want to find the index in the list of the first string that begins with "w".